# Training an Artificial Neural Network with limited-memory Quasi-Newton

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, numerics

I would like to train a simple Artificial Neural Network implementing an algorithm of the class of limited-memory Quasi-Newton.

I read the paper [Modified quasi-Newton methods for training neural networks](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0098135495002286) where they train a NN using the BFGS formula. They also proposed to compute the Hessian by layer (BFGS-L), by neuron (BFGS-N) or mixed (BFGS-M), thus decreasing the total number of partial derivative to compute. As I understood, the true Hessian is computed for each neuron. Clearly is a quasi-Newton. Is it limited-memory?

Instead, [Limited-memory BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS#cite_note-3) approximates the Hessian using the past m iterates and gradients.

1. Are they both limited-memory quasi-Newton?
2. Why choose one over the other?
3. Which one is easier to implement given that I implement the network as a list of layers, each having a list of neurons, and with the weights stored in each neuron?

p.s. maybe this question can be in the Mathematics forum.